# How can I get a matte background printed?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color

How can I get a matte colour printed?
And what is the best app to use?

Comment: Huh? "Best app" for what? Printed how? Commercially? What do you mean by "matte colour"? Typically how "shiny" a color is when printed depends upon the stock (paper) used.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. If by "matte" you mean non-shiny or not glossy, then have it printed on stock with a matte finish. This has nothing to do with apps.

Comment: Hi I mean to print out just a matte solid colour using illustrator o is Adobe in design best to use to create a matte background ?

I’m using the oki laser printer and I use 200gsm silk paper

Comment: It really doesn't matter. The quality of a print consisting of a solid color printed over a large area is *entirely dependent* upon the printer itself. The software used to send the image to the printer is largely irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

## The finish on a print depends on the paper and any coatings used.

Pick up a Pantone swatch book and you'll see what printing the same exact ink on a generic uncoated stock does compared to a generic coated stock.

You can take a printed gloss stock and coat it with a dull or matte varnish to get the same effect (this is not something that desktop printers can do, though. It's something that commercial printers can do).

If you want matte color at home, use a matte or even uncoated paper. This will make everything matte, though, not just the background.